# General question about validation in router

Tags: model, controllers

I have a news-module.

It got a Router.php.

At the moment, I validate in there, if theres an entry in DB for the URL it wants to rout to.
If yes -> got to my news_view.phtml -> if not -> 404

What I want to achieve is to transfer the already loaded collection to my view because I dont want to load it twice. Once for validation in Router and then to display Data in view.

I know bout parameters, but is it a good idea to transfer like 50 lines news-text over parameters?

May I miss something totally here :-/

May someone of you got completely different approach. I am open for everything! Thx in forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Mage::register for this, here you can store data and retreive it in some other place.

To register a variable use:

```
Mage::register('some_name', $var);
```

Then to retreive the value simply use:

```
$my_var = Mage::registry('some_name');
```

And if you want to unload the variable you can use:

```
Mage::unregister('some_name');
```

The values stored in the register are only available during the active request, when you reload your page the register is flushed.

Comment: you have been the first, so you get the point! hope this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Damn it...19 seconds :). @StefanGregori. Yep...that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't know why you get 50 lines in the collection. You should get one or none.
Maybe you should have a different approch on the validation of the url. Add a limit of 1 to the collection.
But anyway...you can use `Mage::register` to remember the loaded data.

```
Mage::register('news_data', $newsData);
```

And in the news view page just check:

```
$newsData = Mage::registry('news_data');
if (!$newsData){
   $newsData = 'Load data again'
}
```

Comment: The meaning by "50 lines" was like my news text(content) itself could be like 50 lines which I dont wanted to transfer with setParam(). Thx for pointing out Mage::register!

Comment: Oh. I get it now. Try to use the `register` method.

Answer (score 0):

My way to find out what is wrong with my adminhtml module:
I've added logging in

`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::collectRoutes()` (at the end)

```
mage::log("collectRoutes:". print_r($this->_modules,1),1,'router.log');
```

and also in   `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::getControllerFileName   mage::log("Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::getControllerFileName\n $file\n",1,'router.log');`

and `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::validateControllerFileName`

```
 mage::log( "Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::validateControllerFileName\n $fileName\not valid/not readable\n",1,'router.log');
```

from these logs I've found out what exactly the router is searching and fixed the issue